# SQL Server union functionality?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a question regarding my attempt to combine two tables in sql server...

I have one table that has about 30 columns (table a), and a second table that has about 5 (table b), those 5 being present in the 30 column table. I want to be able to add table b to the end of table a, and just use 0 values for the nonexistent columns in the new rows.

Is there a way to do this? Obviously a regular union wouldnt work if I want to keep the other columns in table a.

Comment: Are you literally trying to insert the data from `table b` into `table a`? Or just write a `SELECT` statement that accomplishes that without actually changing any data in either table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea is this, assuming `col3` does not exist in `TableB`:

```
select col1, col2, col3 from TableA

union all

select col1, col2, 0 as col3 from TableB
```

Be careful to keep the data types the same within each column.

To keep the `TableB` records at the end, do:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from (
    select 1 as Rank, col1, col2, col3 from TableA

    union all

    select 2 as Rank, col1, col2, 0 as col3 from TableB
) a
order by Rank
```

Comment: Ok this makes a lot of sense, i'll give it a try and report back, thanks.

And yes, select is what im looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked perfectly. I wonder why it wouldn't let me use tableA.* in the first half of the union, and then list them out for table b....but regardless, it all worked, i just had to list out 30 columns twice D:

Comment: In my experience UNION and UNION ALL don't like *, but rather the specific column names, especially in uniting tables that don't have the ALL of the exact same columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can just insert the rows in:

```
insert into A(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
    select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
    from B
```

This will apply the default values for the remaining columns.  The defaults would typically be NULL, but could be changed in the create table statement.  In order to get 0s, you would have to include the columns and specify values:

```
insert into A(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6 . . . col30)
    select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, 0 . . . 0
    from B
```